# NUnit with Windows Phone 7

Tags: nunit, windows-phone-7, unitdriven

I'd like to unit test my Windows Phone 7 libraries with NUnit.

Is there a version of NUnit compatible with Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3):

You might also look at http://unitdriven.codeplex.com - it is a Silverlight and WP7 unit test framework/runner, that also has an add-in DLL for nunit/mstest so you can write tests and have the same test code run in .NET, Silverlight and WP7.

As long as you are testing non-async behaviors, UnitDriven is pretty compatible with nunit (we built it to run a few hundred pre-existing nunit tests). It does have its own model for async tests - again specifically designed so the same test code runs in .NET, SL and WP7.

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for is **[nunit-silverlight](http://code.google.com/p/nunit-silverlight/)**. You need to reference "NUnit.Silverlight.Framework.dll" and "NUnit.Silverlight.Compatibility.dll" (SilverLight 3 versions), and make all references "local copy", even the .NET framework.

If you use Visual Studio *Express Edition*, there is still some obstacles that I detailed a bit more on [my blog](http://guillaumecollic.com/?p=105). In short: *Express Edition* doesn't include tests or add-ins, and it should work fine with external test runners but for my part I've got an exception in NUnit's GUI, so one may need something else to run his tests ([NUnit-Console](http://www.nunit.org), [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/), [Autotest.NET](https://github.com/acken/AutoTest.Net), ...). I use [TddBarForPhone](http://tddbarforphone.codeplex.com/) (available on codeplex), a tool I made which runs NUnit-Console after each build and color the results in red or green.

Comment: Works like a charm for my Windows Phone project(s) - thanks a lot for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

As Windows Phone 7 is basically just Silverlight 3 I suspect that it will be fine.

There are multiple posts about using NUnit with Silverlight, so give them a try and you will probably have lots of success.

Here is one on using TestDriven.Net and NUnit with Silverlight: http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/05/01/silverlight-nunit-projects.aspx

Comment: it looks like the Silverlight NUnit Project template is the easiest solution to start writing NUnit tests against WP7 assembly. Direct link to download: http://www.testdriven.net/downloads/SilverlightNUnitProject.zip

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discoverted the following tools which can be additionaly helpful for CI-Integration.

http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

and more on that (which is a series of articles having 5 parts actually):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2007/11/20/corecon-api-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a [great screencast](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/07/24/Test-Driving-My-Windows-Phone-7-App) recently that shows how to wire up NUnit so you can tdd on the Windows Phone 7 platform.

It's not using any silverlight templates/etc just a plain WP7 class library and NUnit

Answer (score 0):

I've had a port of this ready for a while and finally uploaded it to NuGet.org

```
Install-Package NUnit.WP
```

NuGet package:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.WP

Source: http://bitbucket.org/jesperll/nunit-silverlight