# DivideByZeroException in Webrequest test (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, nunit, dividebyzeroexception

I am using NUnit for testing WP7 application (Install-Package NUnit). I created blank WP Class project with such test:

```
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://google.com");
```

There is such error in this test:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   'System.Net.WebRequest' threw an exception.   ---->
>   System.DivideByZeroException : Attempted to divide by zero.    at
>   System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp(String requestUriString)    at
>   PhoneClassLibrary1.Class1.T() in Class1.cs: line 13
>   --DivideByZeroException    at System.Net.WebRequest..cctor()

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code witouht nunit, and no exception were thrown.
Make sure you got the lastest version of nunit and compatible with silverlight 4.
You can look at this post =>
[NUnit with Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605942/nunit-with-windows-phone-7)

> What you are searching for is nunit-silverlight. You need to reference "NUnit.Silverlight.Framework.dll" and "NUnit.Silverlight.Compatibility.dll" (SilverLight 3 versions), and make all references "local copy", even the .NET framework.

May fix your problem :)